# How to Display mark with high frequency from list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
FDS=[2,3,4,5,6,3,3,3,3]
frequency={}
    for i in FDS:
        if i in frequency:
            frequency[i]+=1
        else:
            frequency[i]=1
    print(frequency)
```

i am getting every element frequency but I need only highest mark frequency

required output:  3

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

```
FDS=[2,3,4,5,6,3,3,3,3]
frequency={}
    for i in FDS:
        if i in frequency:
            frequency[i]+=1
        else:
            frequency[i]=1

print(max(frequency, key=frequency.get))
```